# @propery has retain, should I release?

Tags: objective-c

Say I have:

```
@interface Test : NSObject {
    NSString *string1;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *string1;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation Test
@synthetize property1;
-(id) init {
  if (self=[super init]) {
    NSString *temp = @"testing";
    string1 = [NSString stringWithString:temp];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Do I need to release string1 in dealloc method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and you *also* need to use the accessor method to set it in your `-init`:

```
self.string1 = [NSString stringWithString:temp];
```

If you access the ivar directly, as you did in your question, the new value for the property isn't retained properly.

(*Edit*) Or if, like some folks, you'd rather avoid using accessor methods within `-init`, you need to `-retain` the value manually:

```
string1 = [[NSString stringWithString:temp] retain];
```

Comment: Or just `string1 = [NSString initWithString:temp]`.

Comment: @Adam - If you're going to go that route, it needs to be `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:temp]`. Can't call the initializer unless you've allocated a new instance.

Comment: @Adam: You mean `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:temp]`, of course.

Comment: @Sherm I'm a bit confused. So if I had `string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: temp];`, does this mean I would need two releases (one in init method and one in dealloc)?

Comment: @Ninja - No, because when you assign directly to the `string1` ivar, without using dot syntax, you're not calling the accessor method. So the only `retain` you're doing in that case is the one that's implied by `+alloc`.

Comment: @Ninja - That's also why, in my second example, you need to call retain. You didn't create the new string with a method that already implies ownership, and that example doesn't call the accessor that would automatically retain it for you.

Comment: @Sherm @Josh: D'oh, yes, that's what I meant.