# About retain/release for properties

Tags: objective-c

I have this in my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCTexture2D *tempScreenshot;
```

Since it says "retain", I'm assuming that whatever value is stored in `tempScreenshot` is retained.

Do I have to release `tempScreenshot` in the dealloc method of my class?

Also, if I use the `set` method to give a new value to `tempScreenshot`, this new value will be retained, right? What happens to the `old` value?

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, how come you aren't using ARC?

Comment: @KarolyS: I am using cocos2d-iphone and I find the documentation to convert my game to ARC a bit confusing. But I don't mind: the manual thing is not giving me much trouble anyway. Plus I'd prefer to understand better the manual way before trying to change to automatic.

Comment: Ah, I can understand not wanting to convert(I believe there may even been tools for it though) an already built game. I would highly recommend and future projects use it, it is very useful and simplifies memory management quite a bit!

Comment: @KarolyS: Thank you, I'll definitely consider doing it for all future projects :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [@propery has retain, should I release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511364/propery-has-retain-should-i-release)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Since you're saying "retain" I am assuming this is manual memory management code. If at all possible, you should switch to automatic reference counting (ARC). It dramatically simplifies this work and is faster than the equivalent manual code. Other than support for older OSes, there is almost never a reason to do manual memory management anymore.*

> Since it says "retain", I'm assuming that whatever value is stored in tempScreenshot is retained.

Whenever you call `[self setTempScreenshot:]`, the accessor will retain the parameter and release the old value. Assigning the ivar directly will not give you any of this. You should always use the accessor except in init and dealloc.

> Do I have to release tempScreenshot in the dealloc method of my class?

Yes.

> Also, if I use the set method to give a new value to tempScreenshot, this new value will be retained, right? What happens to the old value?

It will be released as long as you use the accessor.

Answer (score 1):

The `retain` keyword marks the property as *retain upon assignment*, meaning that on a set, `retain` will be called on the new value, **and** `release` will be called on the old value.

You will need to `release` the object on `dealloc`.

Answer (score 1):

In your dealloc method, do: self.tempScreenshot = nil; 
This will cause the object to be released. It will then be deallocated assuming nothing else has retained it.

If you were to write your own setter method to retain an object it would look like this.

```
//Assume an instance variabled name obj for this example
- (void)setAndRetainObjectExample:(NSObject *)newObj {
    [obj release];
    obj = newObj;
    [obj retain];
}
```

Using the synthesized methods is much cleaner, but looking at it this way may clear up any confusion.